# jQuery to check visibility of nested UL and set CSS attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a main nav that runs off of nested UL lists. If a subnav (e.g. ul > ul > ul) is visible, I need to move the body content down a bit.

My HTML structure:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item
            <ul>subnav</ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="bodyMain"></div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#nav ul ul:visible").length === 0) {
        $(".bodyMain").css("padding-top", "50px");
    }
});
```

For some reason, it doesn't work. Here's the page: http://boiseriesboileau.businesscatalyst.com/vostyles.html

Comment: Can you show us CSS? Or fiddle maybe?

Comment: Is it as simple as you need to change to `if($("#nav ul ul:visible").length > 0) {`?

Comment: Here's the page: http://boiseriesboileau.businesscatalyst.com/vostyles.html

Comment: @John S -- I think you may be right... I just changed that on the URL I provided... Let me test more.

Comment: @John S is correct. Duh. Thanks! Feel free to add your comment as a solution so I can approve it.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally checking if there are no visible sub-menus. You should change the if-statement to:

```
if($("#nav ul ul:visible").length > 0) {
```